# I want to know how can I get the value from this print_r shown below

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

Here's the result of

`print_r($response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview)`

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Source] => Product Description
                    [Content] => Acer AO725-0899
                    [IsLinkSuppressed] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Source] => Amazon.com Product Description
                    [Content] => Perfect portability, perfect usability: The AspireÂ® One AO725 N
```

I want to get the value from 0 to Content or 1 to Content , How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep following the chain:

```
$response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content

$response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[1]->Content
```

General rule to finding the data you want from a dump like this:

1. Anything `Array( [x] => ...` means you append `[0]` to your variable.
2. Anything `Object( [x] => ...` means you append `->x` to your variable.

Comment: @SuiGo No problem, updated my answer to help you find your way through future `print_r` outputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds simple enough:

```
echo $response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content;
```

To run through all of them:

```
foreach($response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview as $review)
   echo $review->Content;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo $response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content;  //for 0 contect
echo $response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[1]->Content;  //for 1 content
```

`$response->Items->Item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview` is an array.. use the index of which u want to get the value like...

array[index];

if object use.... ->yourvalue